# Highlighting a table row on hover shows the white-space between columns

Tags: javascript, html, css, highlighting

I have been searching for an answer to this but can't find it on the net.

Basically I want to highlight a table row if the user hovers over it.

I can do this using css or jquery but both show the white space between the columns so it looks pretty ugly.

I was wondering if there was a way to solve this?

The way the columns are spaced out is by using `cellspacing` in the table declaration in the html.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.highlight').hover(function(){
        $(this).children().addClass('datahighlight');
    },function(){
        $(this).children().removeClass('datahighlight');
    });
  });
  </script>`

<table class="gig-table" cellspacing="30">
<tr class="highlight">`
```

In the CSS:

```
.datahighlight { background-color:#cc0099 !important; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
 <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
```

And if you want to have spaces inside your cells use the CSS:

```
  td {padding:10px;}
  tr:hover {background-color:magenta;} /* does not works in old IE versions */
```